# Bugs with Profile Reputation Graph

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, reputation-graph, profile-page

There have been a few bugs with the Rep graph on the user profile page that cause it to display a different value than the actual Rep for the user...

- The +100 Rep bonus from [associating accounts across sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2092/ive-just-seen-my-rep-on-so-jump-by-100-is-this-due-to-a-rep-recalc/2094#2094) does not appear on the Rep graph, making it display 100 less than the true user Rep.
- There was a bug I previously posted on [uservoice](http://stackoverflow.uservoice.com/pages/1722-general/suggestions/202436-bug-with-reputation-tracker-when-hit-with-offensive-penalty-100) having to do with offensive penalties. From the UV post:

  > I recently noticed a user (#82118) who
  >   made a joke that was not very well
  >   received and got hit with a -100
  >   penalty for offensiveness. They had
  >   already earned around 100 points from
  >   upvotes for it.
  >
  > When I looked at their reputation
  >   tracker on their profile, I noticed
  >   that the graph didn't agree with their
  >   reputation (the graph was much lower).
  >   Also, the list next to the graph
  >   showed "0" and "-100" next to the
  >   offending answer, instead of "100-ish"
  >   and "-100".
  >
  > It appears that the reputation tracker
  >   takes away all points earned AND
  >   subtracts 100, even though this is not
  >   what happens to the actual user
  >   reputation. The result is that the
  >   reputation tracker is below the actual
  >   reputation.

Comment: I still see issues: rep on graph is ~10% higher than actual rep http://stackoverflow.com/users/11343?tab=reputation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are still issues with the graph data, but the assocation award and offensive penalties, and bounties are showing up now.

Comment: I just checked a sampling of some Rep graphs, and they do look much closer to the right values now. However, a discrepancy is still apparent when looking at the high-Rep users. For example, Jon's graph (http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656?tab=reputationhistory#tab-top) looks closer to 160k than 175k, and Marc's graph (http://stackoverflow.com/users/23354?tab=reputationhistory#tab-top) looks closer to 130k than 142k. Maybe their graph discrepancies are related to the Rep cap?

Answer (score 6):

I also noticed a bug in the rep graph. Here's a bug report I filed on UserVoice:

> Look at the rep graph for this user:
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/users/4857?tab=reputationhistory
>
> While the profile page says that the
>   user has a rep of 286, the graph seems
>   to indicate that the user has a rep of
>   -747. Adding up the numbers on the table to the right of the graph, it
>   would seem the user should have a rep
>   on or around -730, leading me to
>   suspect that the number in the profile
>   is inaccurate. Unless the user has a
>   large (~1000) source of rep that's not
>   present in the table/graph, I suspect
>   that this person has conned the system
>   into creating more bounties than their
>   rep should allow.

http://stackoverflow.uservoice.com/pages/1722-general/suggestions/202716-user-rep-graph-shows-negative-rep

Comment: While this clearly shows a bug with the Rep graph, I think this bug is more related to a failing of the bounty system. A user shouldn't be able to post bounties they can't cover. Have you seen this with other users? This should probably be a separate question/bug report.

Comment: If that's the case, then certainly - however, I haven't heard of any reports of this, so it's possible that it's just the graph.

Answer (score 4):

I think that rep lost to bounties doesn't appear in the graph

Comment: The user Kyle mentions in his answer appears to have bounty costs included in his Rep graph, making his Rep graph negative even though his Rep (by definition) is not.