# Reputation history graph reports lower than current rep level

Tags: support, reputation-graph, reputation-page

The [Reputation history of my Super User account](https://superuser.com/users/3630?tab=reputationhistory) is showing a lower upper limit on the graph compared to my current reputation. I think this is wrong, is it?

Comment: What, exactly, is wrong about it? What would be correct data?

Comment: i have reputation is more than 5k but its show graph below than 5k

Comment: The graph does not calculate rep 100% exactly the same way the system itself does. It calculates based on Q & A scores, and while it's usually fairly accurate, in some cases, it can appear low. For many users whose reps are 1, for example, it will appear negative because their initial acts on the site may be getting downvoted. See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25405/negative-reputation-display

Comment: Also, is it possible that some of your rep came from questions or answers which may have since been deleted? (If a recalc is done, you will lose that rep.) See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23531/does-the-reputation-graph-indicate-the-results-of-a-recalc/23539#23539

Comment: Dupe? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1543/bugs-with-profile-reputation-graph

Comment: I recalculated your rep on SU. It didn't change much..

Comment: This is a dupe of so many questions, just look at the "Related" list to the right.

Answer (score 3):

It's probably off by 100 - the amount you get for associating your accounts.

If you look at my [Server Fault profile](https://serverfault.com/users/1071?tab=reputationhistory#tab-top) you'll see that the graph stops at just over 600 (as of this writing) while my rep is 731.

The discrepancy is the 100 point bonus I got for associating my accounts.

Answer (score 0):

Flag one of your own posts for a moderator, and ask for a recalc.

Comment: Also, if you go to http://superuser.com/reputation you can see whether this is the cause.