# Reputation graph shifted by one hundred points

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, linked-accounts, reputation-graph

My [reputation graph](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/156050/developer?tab=reputation) shows 30 points, but I have 135 points. I suppose it to be a bug.

There is a [similar problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1543/bugs-with-profile-reputation-graph) from Jul 1 '09 that seems to be solved, but my bug still exists.

Comment: Seems the +100 for associating accounts part of [this bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1543/bugs-with-profile-reputation-graph) might have regressed.

Comment: You mentioned in another post that you received a one-day suspension recently. I don't know what happened in your case, but there's a -100 rep penalty for posting content that gets flagged too much. (EDIT: this doesn't seem to be what's causing your issue, as the -100 should show up in your rep graph history if it's to blame)

Comment: @Popular - I did many retags for a bounty question. I will not do it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Association (and any other bonus) now show up in the rep graph correctly.